# Symfony2: Which is the best way to get root dir?

Tags: symfony, kernel, root

I found 2 methods to get the root dir:

```
1. $rootDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../';
2. $rootDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../';
```

I will use it from defaultAction(). 
Which one is preferred and why?

Comment: I'd probably be inclined to use the latter but I'm sure the difference is negligible.

Comment: I'll choose the second way, because the whole kernel is not called. (but it's primary opinion based. I think this question may be closed)

Comment: there would be hardly anything in it. both services are already active by then anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is minor, you can use the two solutions.

The first use the  `Kernel` service and the last use the `ParameterBag`.
Both are coming from use of `container` and returns a string representing the configured `root_dir`, by default the `app/` directory.